# JQuery mobile datepicker Server datetime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the following date picker in a mobile asp.net mvc razor website 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

1. what i want to do is use server date time instead of client datetime as the default time, where should i place the datetime from my viewbag
2. when my first date field is filled with a date the second date field must have the date + 7 days

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
          ViewBag.datetime1 = System.DateTime.Now
          ViewBag.datetime2 = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
   }

   <div id="startPicker">
      <input id="PickUpDate"  name="PickUpDate" type="date" value="" class="smaller" required="true"/>           
   </div>
   <div id="endPicker">
      <input id="DropOffDate"  name="DropOffDate" type="date" value="" class="smaller"  required="true"/>           
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {

            $(".ui-datepicker").hide();

            // startDate datepicker
            var idDivStart = $("#startPicker div").attr("id");

            $("#PickUpDate").focus(function () {
                $("#" + idDivStart + " .ui-datepicker").show();
            });

            // endDate datepicker
            var idDivEnd = $("#endPicker div").attr("id");

            $("#DropOffDate").focus(function () {
                $("#" + idDivEnd + " .ui-datepicker").show();
            });

            //
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar a").live("click", function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker").hide();
            });

            //
            $(".inputsText").focus(function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker").hide();
            });
            //
            $("div").attr("tabindex", -1).focus(function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker").hide();
            });
        });

   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In document ready set  (if you add ServerDateTime to ViewBag)

```
$("#PickUpDate").datepicker( "setDate" , '@ViewBag.ServerDateTime')

$("#PickUpDate").change(function(){

$("#DropOffDate").datepicker( "setDate" ,$("#PickUpDate".getDate() + 7 ) )

});
```